# Java: How to use Command Line Arguments to add integers in a text file?

Tags: java

I need to use CLAs to control the adding of integers in a file. The first argument is the number of integers to add. The second arg is which other line to skip when adding them( 3 2 should output 72 because it adds 3 integers whilst skipping every 2nd line. The text file is something like

```
7
16
55
4
10
```

I need help on how to implement int M in my code so that it skips the specified line.

```
    int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int M = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

     for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
             x = in.next();
             sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(x);
     }

     System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: What specifically is giving you trouble? It's hard to help you if we don't know what exactly you need help with.

Comment: How do you get 72 out of that input?

Comment: Sorry. I edited my post a bit. I'm not sure on how to use int M so that it skips every other line (if the arg is 2)  when adding up integers.

Comment: What is first argument for? Line to start from or number of integers to sum?

Comment: @Klever first arg is the number of integers to sum. The program should always start from line 1.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but it seems to work

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("FILE_NAME"));

    int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int M = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    int sum = 0;
    int i = 1;

    while (i <= N || scanner.hasNext()) {
        if (i % M != 0) {
            sum += scanner.nextInt();
        } else {
            scanner.nextInt();
            N++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would is store all numbers until `n*m` in an array. It would be much easier that way since you can then iterate and get the sum of the numbers by incrementing by `N`

Something like this:

```
int count = 0, sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < num.length && count < M; i += N) {
    sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(num[i]);
    count++;
}
```

With `2 2 -> sum = 62` and with `3 2 -> sum = 72`

[Demo](https://ideone.com/tLKPmn). I tried to simulate what you are trying to do without reading from file as I am using an online IDE.